Will antenna insulation protect from RF burns?
Will antenna insulation protect from RF burns?
I understand that antennas should normally be built with their insulation on.  Will that insulation protect from RF burns? Up to what power level?
If not: What prevents the feedline from causing RF burns, assuming you don't have a balun?

"I understand that antennas should normally be built with their insulation on." what is the source of that understanding?

RF burning is what heats your food in the microwave oven. It would do the same, whether or not the inner sheet metal surfaces are isolated or not. 
It heats organic material by converting RF energy to heat, primarily by absorption through the forced movement of polar molecules in the high-speed electric field, especially water. (This effect is frequency-dependent, and low frequencies in general do not interact with small bodies very much; but 2.4 GHz, for example, is much more effective at heating water than, say, 3 GHz. The permittivity of water has a higher loss tangent at 2.4 GHz than at 3 GHz. In essence, if you make plate capacitor and fill it with watery stuff rather than air, it will get very low-Q when used at 2.4 GHz, and slightly higher-Q at 3 GHz.)
Direct, low frequency current flow is what burns you when you touch a high voltage power line; it flows as surface current in lines of high current density, and heats things by means of ohmic resistance, mostly.

Insulated wire used for whatever purpose can protect from shocks and burns from DC, AC & AC at RF.  The question is, what power are you putting into that wire, and where on the standing voltage wave of that wire, are you presenting a better return path for the voltage to its source? If you have wire with a 600V insulation rating, that insulation is good for 10s of thousands of Watts at a voltage node, but if you are at the maximum voltage point of the standing voltage wave, then maybe only 120 Watts.
Here is the relationship of voltage and current distributed along a wire, that is a half wavelength, and this distribution repeats indefinitely, with only the current direction changing ever halfwave.

What prevents RF burns on coax is the insulation, but also that the return path is copper braid or aluminum foil, and you are not a better path for that voltage.
